# Switching branches in GIT with uncommitted, auto-generated changes

Tags: git, git-branch, egit

I'm trying to switch local branches in GIT but some auto-generated, ignored and uncommitted files are preventing it.  Is there a way to have these files not prevent me from switching branches?

I have a common workflow. I have a development branch which has some .class files that I generate locally from source.  The .class files are not in the repo and they are ignored.  When I update my local development branch I generate all the class files.  Everything is good.

When I try to switch branches I get warned about all my uncommitted changes in these class files.  I can get around this by switching branches from the command-line with the force switch but this seems silly.  Is there any way to let GIT know it really shouldn't be concerned with these files / folders?

My team is using Eclipse and EGit.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
David R

Comment: Untracked files shouldn't be preventing you from changing branches, unless they happen to match up against some tracked files in that other branch.

Comment: This was the root of the problem. I thought I'd untracked/deleted these files in the branch to which I was switching when I hadn't. This was some good old user error.  I wouldn't have connected the dots that this was the problem on my own.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your other branch probably has those committed and these will clash with what you have in your working dir. You can do one of 2 things:

```
git clean -xdf # to get rid of the untracked files and then you can switch
```

or

```
git clone this-repo # to another place
git checkout -t origin/other-branch 
# clean up the files that should be ignored
git add -A && git commit -m "fixed ignored files" && git push -f
# go back to the original repo
git checkout other-branch # should work now
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to be committing these files, add them to a local .gitignore file.

On a python project, this is what my .gitignore looks like this:

```
.*~
*~
*.py[co]

# Unit test / coverage reports
.coverage
.tox

#Translations
*.mo
```

There is also a [git tree](https://github.com/github/gitignore) of popular .gitignore files for various programming languages and enviroments.

If you want to retain your work but hop of to another branch perhaps to do a quick bug-fix release,
    git stash
is your friend there.

```
git stash save "meaningful message"
```

will save the stash away and allow you to switch branches

```
git stash list
```

will list the various stashes

```
git shash pop <stash id>
```

will restore a stash

Answer (score 0):

Note that is those uncommitted files are still an issue, the [recent EGit2.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.0) now [supports **stash**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.0#Stash_Support).

[image: Egit stash]

And there is a **new stash option** in branch result dialog.
This allows to **quickly stash any conflicting changes that are preventing a branch from being checked out**.